# document click vs element click

Tags: javascript, event-handling

I am wondering if the following is a good concideration.
There might be several links on a page with a data-rel attribute that could be static or ***dynamically*** added with javascript. Instead of adding an eventlistener to each of those I am thinking about adding an eventlistener to the document. I don't want to use jQuery.

Is the following good, or is there a better do add events to dynamically added ellements?

```
var api = {
    function addEvent (evnt, el, func) {
        if (el.addEventListener) { // W3C DOM
            el.addEventListener(evnt,func,false);
        } else if (el.attachEvent) { // IE DOM
            el.attachEvent('on' + evnt, func);
        } else { // No much to do
            el[evnt] = func;
        }
    }
  , removeEvent : function removeEvent (evnt, el, func) {
        if (el.removeEventListener) { // W3C DOM
            el.removeEventListener(evnt,func,false);
        } else if (el.detachEvent) { // IE DOM
            el.detachEvent('on' + evnt, func);
        } else { // No much to do
            el.splice(evnt, 1);
        }
    }
  , checkWhatIsClicked: function checkIfDialog (e) {
        var el = e.srcElement || e.target
          , dataCallback = el.getAttribute('data-callback')
          , dataRel = el.getAttribute('data-rel');

        if (dataRel !== null) {
            switch (dataRel) {
                case 'alert':
                    e.preventDefault();

                    dialogBox.alert();
                    break;
                case 'dialogBox':
                    e.preventDefault();

                    dialogBox.dialog();
                    break;
                case 'prompt':
                    e.preventDefault();

                    dialogBox.prompt();
                    break;
            }
        } else if (dataCallback !== null && el.className.indexOf('dialog-answer') > -1) {
            if (typeof window[dataCallback] === 'function') {
                var result = el.getAttribute('data-result');

                window[dataCallback](result, el);
            }

        }
    }
};

api.addEvent('click', window.document, api.checkWhatIsClicked);
```

Comment: So what is your question?

Comment: if it is a good approach, or is there a better way to do this?

Comment: `addEvent(), click(), removeEvent()`? Now that doesn't make sense. Why not just invoke the listener directly?

Comment: Because I don't know how to attach it automaticaly when some element is dynamically added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's wrong with jQuery?  It doesn't get much easier than:

`$(document).delegate("<identifier>", "<event>", function (e) { do stuff; });`

However, the following link might help you with base javascript event listening and delegation.
https://mattandre.ws/2014/08/small-beautiful-dom-delegation/